# how to sum array values from "for" loop

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code :

```
<tr align="right">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap" align="left"><?= $dt_left_header ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <?php
    //trx data
    for($p=0; $p < count($arr_prd_grp); $p++){
        $prd_id = $arr_prd_grp[$p] ;
        //print_r($arr_prd_grp[$p]);
        if($left_header[$j][1] == 1){
            echo '<td></td>';
        }else{
            echo'
                <td>'.number_format($arr_amt[$coa_id][$prd_id], 2,',','.').'</td>
                ';
        }
    }
    //TOTAL
    if($left_header[$j][1] == 1){
        echo '<td></td>';
    }else{
        echo'
              <td>'.number_format($amt_tot += $arr_amt[$coa_id][$prd_id], 2,',','.').'</td>
            ';
    }

    ?>
</tr>
```

In this case, I want to calculate total of `$arr_amt[$coa_id][$prd_id]` . My code already calculate it but the result is not equal with my expectation. Can someone tell me how to make it right? Thanks

Comment: please add what you are getting and what you are expecting...

Comment: Move summing to the 1st loop

Comment: @YashParekh expected : -2.272.987.032, what I've got : -241.839.381.541.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us a **relevant** example of the data in `$arr_amt` some of this code would make more sense

Comment: @splash58 I've already did, but I got this : -244,112,368,573, my expectation is :  -2.272.987.032

Comment: In any case, you can't do that without loop array by your code or by using any function

Comment: @RiggsFolly : $arr_amt is amount from a product owned by $coa_id and $prd_id

Comment: @splash58 then, what is your advise for this case?

Comment: @Rigen To help you, we need tio know stracture of the array if you are faced with unclear difficulties

Comment: It is VERY Unclear what you are actually trying to achieve from your question and your code

Comment: @splash58 thats no way to copy and paste all of my codes here cause so much line there, what I need is just sum the $arr_amt value

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry for that, the point is sum the $arr_amt value to generate the Total value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the sum calculation to the first loop, then show the result in the appropriate place. To made it easier i've made an extra variable $totalAmount;

Also my guess is that you are having another outer loop (maybe for each table row). Your current code did not default the totalAmount to 0, so it was adding all the ammounts of each rows, thats why you resulted in such a big number. We add a default value 0 for each row to help that.

```
<tr align="right">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap" align="left"><?= $dt_left_header ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <?php
    //trx data
    $totalAmount = 0; // default it
    for($p=0; $p < count($arr_prd_grp); $p++){
        $prd_id = $arr_prd_grp[$p] ;
        //print_r($arr_prd_grp[$p]);
        if($left_header[$j][1] == 1){
            echo '<td></td>';
        }else{
            echo'
                <td>'.number_format($arr_amt[$coa_id][$prd_id], 2,',','.').'</td>
                ';
                $totalAmount+=$arr_amt[$coa_id][$prd_id];
        }
    }
    //TOTAL
    if($left_header[$j][1] == 1){
        echo '<td></td>';
    }else{
        echo'
              <td>'.number_format($totalAmount, 2,',','.').'</td>
            ';
    }

    ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for ur help, my problem solved. The first row already correct, but the next row it return a big number. I'll try to catch it up, once again thanks Simos :))